# Angular Universal app not honoring 'useAbsoluteUrl' or HTTP Interceptor on server-side

Tags: node.js, asp.net, typescript, express, angular-universal

Our Angular 14 app is configured to use Angular Universal for SSR, and is integrated with our .NET 6 back end. The Universal guide [incorrectly states](https://angular.io/guide/universal#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20one%20of%20the%20%40nguniversal/*%2Dengine%20packages%20(such%20as%20%40nguniversal/express%2Dengine)%2C%20this%20is%20taken%20care%20for%20you%20automatically.%20You%20don%27t%20need%20to%20do%20anything%20to%20make%20relative%20URLs%20work%20on%20the%20server.) (per [this bug](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1826)) that relative URLs will "automatically" be converted to absolute if you're using Express, but we still get relative URL errors from SSR even after updating our `app.server.module.ts` to include the necessary setting **.useAbsoluteUrl = true** (and providing the base URL), which fixes the issue for some per the bug thread:

```
export class AppServerModule {
  constructor(
    @Inject(INITIAL_CONFIG) private config: PlatformConfig,
    private baseUrlService: BaseUrlService
  ) {
      this.config.baseUrl = this.baseUrlService.getBaseUrl();
      this.config.useAbsoluteUrl = true;
    }
}
```

We've also tried implementing a [custom HTTP Interceptor](https://bcodes.io/blog/post/angular-universal-relative-to-absolute-http-interceptor) to handle the conversion, which doesn't seem to work either when declared as a provider in `app.server.module.ts`. This must be a misconfiguration issue, right? Our `main.server.ts` file imports the `aspnet-prerendering` package and has a default **createServerRenderer()** method, which calls **renderModule(AppServerModule, options)**, but is something else missing with this approach? The `main.server.ts` is:

```
....
export default createServerRenderer(params => {
const { AppServerModule } = (module as any).exports;

const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin }
    ]
};

// Bypass ssr api call cert warnings in development
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

const renderPromise = renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

return renderPromise.then(html => ({ html }));
});

export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

Microsoft's now-deprecated NodeServices implementation(?) apparently requires the use of **commonjs** for Node (in `tsconfig.server.json`), if that's relevant.